# Extraer un fragmento de una cadena variante en Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo una cadena de fecha tal como así: `1-Ene-2017`, también se presenta el caso que sea así: `28-Ene-2017`, lo que intento hacer es obtener la parte de la cadena del mes es decir: `Ene`.

Hasta el momento no he podido obtener la cadena que deseo, esto es lo que eh intentado:

```js
function formatDate(date) {  
        var MonthName=["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"];
        var MonthName2=["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
        alert("" + date.substring(date.indexOf('-') + 1, 6));
        var mes = "";
        for(i=0; i<12; i++) {
         if(date.substring(date.indexOf('-') + 1, 6) == MonthName[i]) {
          mes = MonthName2[i];
         }
        }
        alert("MES: " + mes);
    }
formatDate('28-Ene-2017');
formatDate('1-Ene-2017');
```

Tendrán alguna idea de como obtener la cadena que deseo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una alternativa puede ser que realices un `split('-')` y captures el indice 1

```js
var fecha = '01-Ene-2017';

var result = fecha.split('-')[1];

console.log(result);
```

El [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) lo que hace es cortar un string por cada carácter que se le indique dentro de las comillas en este caso `('-')` y lo transforma en un `array`.

En el ejemplo el resultado del split seria `[01, Ene, 2017]` y accedemos al indice 1 de ese array que en este caso es `Ene`.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar expresiones regulares para obtener el mes.

Si usas el patrón `/[a-zA-Z]{3}/` entonces vas a capturar la cadena que incluya tres letras (el mes, ya que el resto o son dígitos o son guiones).

```js
var patron = /[a-zA-Z]{3}/;

var date1 = "1-Ene-2017";
var date2 = "28-Feb-2017";

var mes1 = patron.exec(date1);
var mes2 = patron.exec(date2);

console.log(mes1);
console.log(mes2);
```

Comment: Ahora es cuando @Mariano ve el patrón y se echa a llorar diciendo "¿por qué? ¡¿por qué?!!!" :P