# Conocer ultimo dia del mes entre 2 fechas AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Saludos, tengo un problema en mi controlador con **AngularJS**, tengo un objeto que me trae lo siguiente

```
Objeto{
FechaInicio: "2017-11-04"
FechaTermino: "2017-03-04"
}
```

Necesito la manera que me diga las últimas fechas del mes que existen en ese intervalo de tiempo y yo con eso crear un nueva nueva lista que debe quedar algo así:

```
nuevaLista {
fechaFin[0]: 2017-11-30, //(30 dias)
fechaFin[1]: 2017-12-31,  //(31 días)
fechaFin[2]: 2018-01-01,  //(31 días)
fechaFin[3]: 2018-02-28,  //(28 días o 29 si aplica)
}
```

Estoy revisando la libreria `moment (moment().endOf(String);)` pero no se como hacer para que calcule solo en ese intervalo.

Answer (score 1):

ultimo dia del mes en una fecha

```
var fecha = new Date(f.anofin1.value, f.mesfin1.value, 0).getDate();
```

Ejemplo :  *fecha = 2018-07-15;*

```
var fecha = new Date(2018, 07, 0).getDate();
```

Resultado :  *fecha = 31;*

Answer (score 0):

lo puedes hacer solo con Javascript, puede tener una [variación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121270/extraer-un-fragmento-de-una-cadena-variante-en-javascript) la respuesta

```js
let fechaInicio = "2017-11-04";
function ultimoDiaMes(fecha){
  let arrayFecha = fecha.split('-');
  let fechaUltimo = new Date(arrayFecha[0], arrayFecha[1]) 
  fechaUltimo.setDate(fechaUltimo.getDate() - 1)

  return fechaUltimo.toLocaleString()
} 
console.log(ultimoDiaMes(fechaInicio));
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo hice con la librería momment

```
  let fechafinMes = moment(fechaaCalcular).endOf('month');
```

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/76980)

Comment: Gracias por la edición, publiqué la solución que me funcionó, por si alguien la necesita :) y yo no coloqué "let" en dado caso "var" o "$scope"